# Exception thrown when loading sound- but things work anyway

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have the following lines to preload a couple of (short) sounds in a sound-storing singleton (from which they can then be grabbed when need to play arises)

```
_successSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"success2.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
_failureSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"failure2.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
```

When i run my application with an exception breakpoint (which I tend to always do), it breaks on the second line. Removing the breakpoint, everything instead works as expected. I had previously done this 'loading' only when the sound was to be played (which caused a slowdown the first time it had to be played), and it never caused any exceptions.

Edit: should also add that there aren't any exception if I change the failure2 sound to some other sound in my soundfolder- perhaps it's something to do with it being mp3?

Answer (score 1):

OS code can throw exceptions that are caught and never visible to the outside, and that's inconvenient if you set a breakpoint on exceptions but nothing to worry about and not something that you need to avoid, as long as there are no uncaught exceptions.

It happens a lot with APIs that are implemented in C++ - throwing and catching exceptions is much more common in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got rid of the exception by converting the `mp3` to `wav`. If anyone knows why this was a problem in the first place though, I'd be very interested.

Comment: The [SKAction documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:) indicates that `playSoundFileNamed` is only meant for short incidental sounds, which would generally only be distributed as uncompressed WAVs or CAFs (something similar can be seen with the system short sound APIs). It says that AVAudioPlayer (which *does* support MP3, among other compressed lossy formats) should be used for longer running background music.

Comment: That isn't a definitive answer though, just my guess.

Comment: The mp3 is just ~2 sec, but it seems like the most reasonable answer is that support for the mp3 format has some issues.